# Inherit odoo javascript search box

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12, odoo-13

Inherit odoo javascript search box
Hey guys, i need to inherit this: addons/web/static/src/js/views/control_panel/search/search_filters.js
code snippet:

```
'''var Char = Field.extend({
tagName: 'input',
className: 'o_input',
attributes: {
    type: 'text'
},
operators: [
    {value: "ilike", text: _lt("contains")},
    {value: "not ilike", text: _lt("doesn't contain")},
    {value: "=", text: _lt("is equal to")},
    {value: "!=", text: _lt("is not equal to")},
    {value: "∃", text: _lt("is set")},
    {value: "∄", text: _lt("is not set")}
],
get_value: function () {
    return this.$el.val();
});
```

I want to add one more line there,
{value: '=ilike', text: _lt("matches")},

I tried inheriting that whole file, and after adding the line nothing happens.
Any hint is appreciated.
That line comes from the module
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/web_advanced_search_wildcard/
but its only for v12, i need it on v13 and higher.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the line where they get the `Char` filter reference because `core.search_filters_registry` is undefined in Odoo13:

```
var Char = require('web.search_filters').Char;
```

***Example*** (adding a new operator to the char filter)***:***

```
var core = require('web.core');
var Char = require('web.search_filters').Char;
var _lt = core._lt;
Char.prototype.operators.push(
  {value: '=ilike', text: _lt("Matches")}
);
```

You will need to create a new file and add it to an [asset bundle](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#adding-files-in-an-asset-bundle) (`web.assets_backend`).